In qiskit, the set crosstalk noise model does not work,the output result is the ideal state, not the result with noise
n_qubits = 4
circ = QuantumCircuit(n_qubits)

# Test Circuit
circ.h(0)
for qubit in range(n_qubits - 1):
    circ.cx(qubit, qubit + 1)
circ.measure_all()
print(circ)

always_on_noise_model = NoiseModel()

zz_prob = 0.01

zz_error = pauli_error([('ZZ', zz_prob), ('II', 1 - zz_prob)])

for qubit_pair in [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (0, 2), (1, 3), (0, 3)]:
    always_on_noise_model.add_quantum_error(zz_error, 'cx', qubit_pair)
print(always_on_noise_model )

backend = AerSimulator(method='automatic',noise_model=always_on_noise_model)

circ_tnoise = transpile(circ, backend)

result_bit_flip = backend.run(circ_tnoise).result()
counts_bit_flip = result_bit_flip.get_counts(0)

print(counts_bit_flip)

Result:{'0000': 519, '1111': 505}
The output result is the ideal state, not the result with noise.The correct result should be {'1111': 500, '0000': 492, '0100': 7, '1101': 3, '1011': 5, '0010': 6, '1110': 7, '0001': 4}

Pauli $ZZ$ error will only add phase errors to your circuit. I believe the result you are expecting is for Pauli $XX$.
Replacing:
zz_error = pauli_error([('ZZ', zz_prob), ('II', 1 - zz_prob)])

with:
xx_error = pauli_error([('XX', xx_prob), ('II', 1 - xx_prob)])

in your code, yields the expected results:
{'0001': 3, '1110': 2, '1100': 5, '1111': 497, '0011': 4, '0000': 513}
